# X throws out errors when forkpty is called. (C++)

Tags: c++, linux, qt, x11, pty

When my program gets to this line:

```
pid_t nPid = forkpty( &m_nMasterFD, NULL, NULL, NULL );
```

Outputs this:

```
X Error: BadIDChoice (invalid resource ID chosen for this connection) 14
  Extension:    148 (RENDER)
  Minor opcode: 17 (RenderCreateGlyphSet)
  Resource id:  0x3600002
<unknown>: Fatal IO error 4 (Interrupted system call) on X server :0.0.
```

And terminates. As you can see, I'm trying to make a pty to run stuff in, but it's not working.

Also, is there a way `forkpty()` can be called within a class? ( I tried both ways, but neither worked. )

I'm programming in QT C++ on Ubuntu 9.10.

EDIT: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155314/simplest-way-to-get-a-pty-in-linux-c) a link to the question with the code that finally worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

forkpty() forks your process. You need to close the filedescriptors first, in particular the connection to the X server in your child process. This means you likely cannot use forkpty , but have to use openpty(), fork(),close filedescriptors in the child process, logintty/()

Comment: Isn't this what `O_CLOEXEC` is for?

Comment: If you exec() a new program, yes. In this case there's just fork().

Comment: Oh.  Somehow I thought that `forkpty()` had a final `exec` in there, but no, of course it doesn't...