# How to run an adb shell command and remain in the shell?

Tags: android, shell, adb

Does anyone know how to run commands from adb shell and remain in shell session? 
What I`m trying to achieve is to set aliases in adb shell.

I have tried the following without success

```
adb shell <<< "ls"
```

After executing this command indeed remain in shell, but cannot receive output of any further command.

I have also tried the following:

```
adb shell <<EOF
ls
EOF
```

with the same result.

Answer (score 31):

When you run:

```
adb shell ls
```

You are running this command currently outside of ADB.

First, you need to enter ADB:

```
adb shell
```

Once you enter ADB shell, you can continue to see output and input more commands.

```
ls
help
```

To exit ADB, simply type "exit" or hit "Ctrl + C"

Answer (score 8):

**`expect` solution**

This will run the command, and leave you in an ADB shell automatically.

adb-cmd

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
spawn adb shell
expect "#"
send [ concat [ join $argv " " ] ]
send "\r"
interact
```

Usage:

```
adb-cmd 'cd /data/data; ls'
```

Tested in Ubuntu 16.04 host, Android O guest.

Comment: Brilliant! I'm a pretty new user of `adb` this saved my sanity!

Comment: @TedLyngmo worry not, Android will sooner or later find a way to consume your sanity! :-)

Answer (score 5):

There was a similar question answered in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5852578/3638059).

In short, run the following from your terminal:

`stty raw -echo ; ( echo "ls" && cat ) | adb shell ; stty sane`

Note: without the `stty` magic, the command is piped to `adb` and tab complete etc. is not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

```
            //you can use a nodejs script as below:
            //let input='shell script here' 
            let input='cd /data/local/tmp\nchmod +x a.out\n./a.out\n'
            p=run("adb.exe",args:'shell',cb:rs=>lg(rs)})
            p.stdout.on("data",rs=>{
            lg(rs)
            setInterval(_=>process.exit(),2000);
            })
            p.stdin.write(input)

            //+++++++++++++++++++++++++
            function lg(...args){
            console.log(...args);
            }

            function run(cmd,args,cb){
            if(args) cmd= cmd+" "+args;
            return require('child_process').exec(cmd,(er,stdout,stderr)=>{ 
            if(er) return cb(stdout||stderr,false);
            stdout=stdout==''?true:stdout;
            cb(stdout,true)

            });
            }
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.