# Entering ADB shell within a specific directory on the connected device using only a single line of terminal code

Tags: android, shell, adb

I'm trying to find a single line solution for entering a shell using ADB on an android device and going straight into a different directory.

Trying something like this

```
./adb shell cd /insert_dir_here
```

does not work.

Comment: I understand your query, However once the command is executed, the control is returned back to the `host shell`. Example : `adb shell "cd /tmp && ls"` - Will `cd` into `tmp`, `list` contents of `tmp`, finally returning control to the Host. Its doing what its suppose to do, however I doubt that the control can be retained. Hopefully some way to do it *Fingers crossed* :)

Comment: Also it would help to know your *actual objective* after this step, Are you trying to run some application or some script after `cd` into the `dir` ?

Comment: I'm basically iterating through directories of the connected device. I'm currently using Applescript to make a little file transfer app, later on today I will be making a cocoa xcode project for it. The main thing I need to be able to do is, iterate through directories of the device, any suggestions are welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Following `adb shell` with a command, executes it remotely and returns to the hosts shell right after that.
so `./adb shell cd /insert_dir_here` does work, but the shell exits right away.

what kind of commands do you want to execute after changing the directory?

I suggest using the command `alias` followed with your series of commands:

```
alias myADB="cd /to/path; command1 args; command2 args; etc...."
```

then execute your alias in your own shell "not the adb shell"

```
myADB
```

Comment: I guess so! I have found threads already giving this solution, I was hoping for something simpler. Anyways thanks for the answer! +1  for you

Answer (score 1):

**`expect` solution**

`adb-cmd`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
spawn adb shell
expect "#"
send [ concat [ join $argv " " ] ]
send "\r"
interact
```

Then:

```
adb-cmd cd /data/
```

Likely this can be improved by someone who knows more Tcl than me.

Superset: [adb shell run command and remain in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383309/adb-shell-run-command-and-remain-in-shell)