# How do I accept piped input and then user-prompted input in a Python script?

Tags: python, input, user-input

I have a script that is designed to accept input piped in from stdin and then prompt the user for more input. Here is a contrived example illustrating what I mean:

```
import sys

# Get input from stdin
input_nums = [int(n.strip()) for n in sys.stdin]

# Prompt user
mult = int(raw_input("Enter a number by which to multiply your input: "))

for num in input_nums:
    print num*mult
```

When I pipe data in from stdin, python interprets stdin as closed before it gets to `raw_input` and it gives an `EOFError: EOF when reading a line`:

```
[user]$ cat nums.txt
2
3
4
5
[user]$ cat nums.txt | python sample.py
Enter a number by which to multiply your input: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample.py", line 6, in <module>
    mult = int(raw_input("Enter a number by which to multiply your input: "))
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

(Please don't worry about the useless use of `cat`... its just a minimal example)

What I want to know is if there is a way to somehow separate reading sys.stdin and calling `raw_input` so that I can both pipe in data and then prompt a user for input.

**Updated to make it more clear what I really want by eliminating red herrings, and added traceback of EOFError**

**Result** @TimPeter's solution worked for me, but I had to change "CON:" to "/dev/tty" since I'm on UNIX, not Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect you're out of luck, at least for any kind of cross-platform solution.  Python uses `sys.stdin` for `raw_input()`, and if you invoke Python so that `sys.stdin` is on the receiving end of a pipe, Python can't do anything to magically change `sys.stdin` to the terminal when the piped input ends.

[Here's a variant of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843741/how-can-i-pipe-initial-input-into-process-which-will-then-be-interactive) with a Unix-specific workaround as the accepted answer.  That cleverly worms around some (not all) of the problem by changing the way the program is **invoked**.

Sorry.

### One way

This seems to work fine for Windows:

```
import sys
print len(sys.stdin.read()) # anything to consume piped input
sys.stdin = open("CON:", "r")
x = raw_input("sdfklj ")
```

That is, after reading the piped-in input, `sys.stdin` is rebound to the special file `CON:` (which is what Windows calls a DOS box) opened in read mode.

See your Unix docs for what to try there - perhaps `/dev/tty1`?  There are mounds of  terminal control options you **may** need to fiddle with too, depending on platform specifics.  That's why I said (at the start) that I think you're out of luck for any cross-platform solution.  Python has no special support for terminal devices; i.e., you're on your own for that.

Comment: Thanks, but this is a program that I will be used by my co-workers, and I don't want to force them to call the script in an odd way.  Good suggestion, though.

Comment: Then do your coworkers a favor and give them just one way to run the program - then it will work, and they won't be confused either - LOL ;-)  Seriously, can you think of any other program, of any kind, that works the way you intend here?  Excessive novelty is confusing on its own.

Comment: Even if I were to choose to only accept piped in data, I would need to still prompt the user for data.  Let me edit the question to make that more clear.  In reality the program is more complex and prompting the user is a must, and the input data is taken from the output of another co-worker's program.

Comment: And yes, grep works this way (without the prompting, of course)

Comment: I admire determination ;-)  I added an edit showing how to do it on Windows.  It "should be" easier on Unix-y systems, but somehow I doubt it ;-)

Comment: YEAH!  It works on UNIX when I replace "CON:" with "/dev/tty".  I don't need a cross platform solution, but if one did, maybe a `if sys.plaform == 'win32'... else` could work in this situation.

Comment: Woohoo!  Delighted to hear it, @SethMMorton - now just think of a way we can get rich off this - LOL ;-)

Comment: I realize that this is bad form, but could you take a look at [my question about Python's C API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20875520/1399279)?  I was hoping that one of the core developers could provide some insight.