# Pass input to interactive command line program in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, echo, cat

I have a program that has its own prompt

```
example_program>
```

I need to run a series of command via this program

```
example_program> command_A
example_program> command B
Please enter input: [input_here]
example_program> command C
```

I can send commands A,B,C via the following line in a shell script:

```
(echo "command_C" && cat) | (echo "command_B" && cat) | (echo "command_A" && cat ) | example_program
```

How can I enter in the input needed and am prompted for after command B ([input_here])?

I do not have access to send or expect.

Comment: Similar but not the same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843741/how-can-i-pipe-initial-input-into-process-which-will-then-be-interactive

Comment: Trying to do this without dbus or gui: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Connman#Connecting_to_a_protected_access_point

Comment: The `&& cat` is unnecessary and quite possibly a bug. Why do you put that in and what do you hope for it to do? It will want to read data from standard input.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing this will work, but it's only a guess since we don't know how your program is reading the responses: use a here-doc, and put the input for command B after invoking command B

```
example_program <<'END'
command_A
command B
input_here
command C
END
```

Comment: I tried a here-doc but it is trying to execute "input_here" as a command instead of supplying the input for command_B

Comment: @tim, what's happening after command_B? What happens at the "input here" prompt? Do you have any visibility into the code for the program (i.e. does it read from stdin or the tty or what?)