# Interactive command in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to automate a creation of a development Docker image using `docker build` command with appropriate `Dockerfile`. One of the scripts that I need to run in a `RUN` command wants the user to click through and read their license agreement. Thus there are two questions:

1. Where is the output of all the `RUN` commands in a `Dockerfile`?
2. What solution is possible to interact with the aforementioned command? Right now the `docker build` command just gets stuck asking user for input in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The output of `RUN` commands is shown in your terminal during the build. The Docker build process is completely non-interactive, so you must find some way of either auto-accepting the terms (almost every piece of software allows this, think `apt-get install -y...`) or using some shell wizardry to echo the acceptance back to the process or whatever ([Expect](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/expect/) maybe?).

Comment: Yes, I do use `-y` for `apt-get` type of applications. But this one is some commercial thing.

Comment: Yes, commercial things are usually really shitty ;) But I'd be surprised if they didn't have a non-interactive mode :) If not then look into Expect.

Comment: I have similar issue. I am installing conda(arm based image is not available at present) in docker while building the image. Code looks like `RUN bash Anaconda3-2021.04-Linux-aarch64.sh` and that's where things go wrong because it requires entering multiple times yes. Any suggestion how it can be handled.

Comment: Is there a link to how to use expect in the dockerfile?

Comment: @Vineet you usually do `yes | <some command requiring pressing "y">`. See `man yes`.

Answer (score 25):

You can also do it in several steps, begin with a Dockerfile with instructions until before the interactive part. Then

`docker build -t image1 .`

Now just

`docker run -it --name image2 image1 /bin/bash`

you have a shell inside, you can do your interactive commands, then do something like

`docker commit image2 myuser/myimage:2.1`

The doc for `docker commit`

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/

you may need to specify a new CMD or ENTRYPOINT, as stated in the doc

Commit a container with new CMD and EXPOSE instructions

For example some docker images using wine do it in several steps, install wine, then launch and configure the software launched in wine, then `docker commit`

Answer (score 5):

You can use the technique [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5852578/3869199):

```
(echo "initial command" && cat) | some_tool
```

Or, if multiple stages use `printf` and concat with `\n`:

```
(printf "cmd1\ncmd2" && cat) | some_tool
```

Comment: `(echo "passwword" && cat) | sudo ls ` doesn't work and I took sudo as a common example of an interactive tool.

Comment: @Atomosk Many console-based programs like `sudo` do not read sensitive data like passwords from stdin, but more directly from the terminal. You can use `-S` to make `sudo` read from stdin.

Comment: @creativecoding I know about -S, what is why I said that `sudo` is just an common example. Everyone can test and see that `echo` won't help you with that.

Comment: I tested it on APT and some some terms that needed to be accepted and it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a tool like [`expect`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) to automate the user interaction.

1. Add `expect` to your image (preferably a build step because you will not need it later). E.g.

```
RUN apt update && apt install -yq expect
```

2. Create a script to run, something like:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env expect
set timeout 10
spawn some_program_that_requires_interaction.sh
expect "Some string that we want to wait for"

# send newline, simulating pressing enter:
send -- "\r"
expect eof
```

3. Copy the script into your image and run it:

```
COPY my_expect_script .
RUN sh my_expect_script
```

This is totally untested, and it's difficult to know how well it'll work with your specific scenario. `Expect` doesn't work so well when curses is involved (or any kind of CLI UI that plays around with cursor position), so your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

To see output of all commands during build, if they are not showing up in enough detail for you, try:

`docker build --progress=plain --no-cache -t yourTag .`