# Trying to install selenium python3 package on docker image

Tags: python-3.x, docker, selenium-webdriver, pip, dockerfile

I've tried unsuccessfully to re-build a docker image with selenium python package on it. I'm not sure how to proceed.

Here's my dockerfile:

```
FROM selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
WORKDIR /usr/local/bin
RUN sudo apt-get update
RUN sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
RUN sudo apt-add-repository universe
RUN sudo apt-get install python-pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install .
RUN pip3 install -e .
COPY ./* ./
```

I'm fairly sure it's my dockerfile that's wrong, but after trying various methods of installing pip I'm drawing a blank.

In any case I'm then calling:
    docker build -t webdriver .

Which outputs the following:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.608kB
Step 1/10 : FROM selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
 ---> 11258d1f9aba
Step 2/10 : WORKDIR /usr/local/bin
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9297517083f6
Step 3/10 : RUN sudo apt-get update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f9004a85fc1a
Step 4/10 : RUN sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
 ---> Running in bb2336c4ae46
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  apt-utils cron gir1.2-glib-2.0 iso-codes libapt-inst2.0 libcurl3-gnutls
  libgirepository-1.0-1 librtmp1 python-apt-common python3-apt python3-dbus
  python3-gi python3-pycurl python3-software-properties unattended-upgrades
  xz-utils
Suggested packages:
  anacron logrotate checksecurity exim4 | postfix | mail-transport-agent
  isoquery python3-apt-dbg python-apt-doc python-dbus-doc python3-dbus-dbg
  libcurl4-gnutls-dev python-pycurl-doc python3-pycurl-dbg bsd-mailx
  mail-transport-agent
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apt-utils cron gir1.2-glib-2.0 iso-codes libapt-inst2.0 libcurl3-gnutls
  libgirepository-1.0-1 librtmp1 python-apt-common python3-apt python3-dbus
  python3-gi python3-pycurl python3-software-properties
  software-properties-common unattended-upgrades xz-utils
0 upgraded, 17 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 3615 kB of archives.
After this operation, 22.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
The command '/bin/sh -c sudo apt-get install software-properties-common' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I'm guessing that "Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort." needs to be answered "Y", but I don't know how to do this. I suspect I'm missing more though.

Needless to say my python script still doesn't run as it needs selenium:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "web-test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
```

Can anyone tell me where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Try using the `-y` flag with `sudo apt-get install`. Essentially, `sudo apt-get install -y software-properties-common`. This will assume yes for all install calls with `apt-get`.

Comment: @Abdou Thanks for the input - that's gotten me further. I've now uncovered package dependency issues that I'm going to try to work through.

Comment: What kind of dependency issues? `python` or OS packages?

Answer (score 0):

You have identified the error correctly. You need to answer the question: `Do you want to continue? [Y/n]` with `Y` and continue. So, change your docker file as follows and add the flag `-y`

```
FROM selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
WORKDIR /usr/local/bin
RUN sudo apt-get -y update
RUN sudo apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN sudo apt-add-repository -y universe
RUN sudo apt-get install -y python3-pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install .
RUN pip3 install -e .
COPY ./* ./
```

The -y flag can be used to assume `YES` for all apt installs. You need to add the `-y` flag, because `docker build` command cannot be run in an interactive mode. Hence, all interactions in the build process have to be added in the `Dockerfile`. ([Read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40854880/4388776))

Since you are gonna use `pip3` you need to install it correctly. You are trying to install `pip2`. I have updated the your docker file accordingly. You need to use the below command to install pip3.

`RUN sudo apt-get install -y python3-pip`

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things in your Dockerfile:

- Avoid installing or using **sudo** as it has unpredictable TTY and signal-forwarding behavior that can cause problems. You can refer to [Dockerfile Best Practice](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/)

```
RUN sudo apt-get update
RUN sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
RUN sudo apt-add-repository universe
RUN sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

- The message

```
Need to get 3615 kB of archives.
After this operation, 22.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
The command '/bin/sh -c sudo apt-get install software-properties-common' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

You need to add the flag `-y` to your Docker command above, so that during the Docker building, it can automatically say `Yes` for you.