# How to send user input as some text inside Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install ttf-dejavu
COPY ./soap.sh /
RUN chmod +x /soap.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/soap.sh"]
CMD ["/script.sh", "arg1"]
```

I am trying to install SoapUI using above Dockerfile.

Using above Dockerfile, I am able to build the image Successfully as shown below:

```
root@test00-new:/home/sam/1_Docker# docker build -t balu1 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  385.8MB
Step 1/8 : FROM ubuntu
 ---> 1e4467b07108
Step 2/8 : MAINTAINER Sample
 ---> Running in c6dc0992d25c
Removing intermediate container c6dc0992d25c
 ---> 7ecd8a4fcbfd
Step 3/8 : RUN apt-get -y update
 ---> Running in aa6467b0fc5c
 ---> cd3b7f8f5389
Step 4/8 : RUN apt-get -y install ttf-dejavu
 ---> Running in 8fcc7ce6ab9f
 ---> 55649115b86c
Step 5/8 : COPY ./soap.sh /
 ---> 2c236754e2d5
Step 6/8 : RUN chmod +x /soap.sh
 ---> Running in 408d72761df5
Removing intermediate container 408d72761df5
 ---> 17d2afb0bc43
Step 7/8 : ENTRYPOINT ["/soap.sh"]
 ---> Running in 0b10d8b91d65
Removing intermediate container 0b10d8b91d65
 ---> a7d0b50d4fdd
Step 8/8 : CMD ["/script.sh", "arg1"]
 ---> Running in a8ba5d134b5d
Removing intermediate container a8ba5d134b5d
 ---> d41cffedccda
Successfully built d41cffedccda
Successfully tagged balu1:latest
root@test00-new:/home/sam/1_Docker# docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
balu1               latest              d41cffedccda        29 seconds ago      351MB
ubuntu              latest              1e4467b07108        3 weeks ago         73.9MB
root@test00-new:/home/sam/1_Docker#
```

But When I run the docker using above image, I am getting the following output:

```
root@test00-new:/home/sam/1_Docker# docker run balu1 OK
Unpacking JRE ...
Preparing JRE ...
Starting Installer ...
This will install SoapUI 5.2.1 on your computer.
OK [o, Enter], Cancel [c]
root@test00-new:/home/sam/1_Docker#
```

In the above case how to handle user input in Dockerfile?

I need to send a letter o or ENTER as input inside Dockerfile

I tried by running "docker run balu1 0", "docker run balu1 OK" etc. But its not working.

Please guide me on this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interactive command in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40854482/interactive-command-in-dockerfile)

Comment: Got it Thanks @Suman Let me try and update

Comment: What do "soap.sh" and "script.sh" do?

Comment: Can you share the contents of `soap.sh` and `script.sh`. That dialogue is generated by a command that is launched from one of those scripts. There might be some options to run that command silently.

Comment: @NeoAnderson I downloaded SoapUI-x64-5.2.1.sh from the following location and renamed as soap.sh:

https://www.soapui.org/downloads/soapui/soapui-os-older-versions/

And also I want pass some arguments like Username and Password also.

Comment: A quote from soapui page: _At this time, we do not have any short term plans to modify the installer to include additional silent options._