# Keep GDB prompt interactive while reading from stdin?

Tags: gdb

I [automate](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Command-Files.html) my gdb script like this

```
gdb -q --args the_program <<EOL
# breakpoints etc.
run
EOL
```

Works fine, however when interrupting the running process with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the entire process falsely **exits**:

> Quit anyway? (y or n) [answered Y; input not from terminal]

, meaning gdb is not interactive anymore. How do I prevent this?

For some reason, the interrupt signal works fine when using an external commands file like `gdb ... -x the_commands_file`. But this question is about the stdin-way. Is there a possibility to send the desired commands via *stdin* but *still* be able to keep interaction possible afterwards?

Comment: Here's how to use `expect` to do this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97410/why-is-expects-interact-command-not-working

Comment: @MarkPlotnick about your previous comment: I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/5852578/3779853. This *does* change the behaviour, however when the commands include a `run` (like `(echo run && cat) | gdb ...`), an interrupt leads to a quit again. // Expect would surely work

Comment: My previous comment, which I deleted after I found an existing answer on unix.stackexchange.com, suggested writing to `/proc/pid/fd/0` or using `expect`. Using `(echo ...; cat) | ...` would be fine for a noninteractive command, but not for gdb, where you'd want interrupts and character-at-a-time input to work. Typing ^C kills the cat.