# How to create a console terminal?

Tags: c++, user-interface, console, terminal, vt100

From where I can start creating a console for my C++ programs ?

I need a bare minimum console to launch and manage console applications, the reason why I need this it's because I need to pack everything into 1 executable and create and control my little environment.

With the term "console" I only mean a terminal to run my program, nothing more, nothing less, **I don't want my console to be interfaced with the underlaying system**, only care about my console applications.

So my question is: given a C++ applications or a command line interpreter, what is the know-how required to create a terminal that is able to interface itself to this application and report and manage the usual input ( std::cout, special characters like bells, text input from the user, and so on ) ?

Comment: Your options are *radically* different depending on whether or not you're on Windows.  Please indicate.

Comment: Also, either way, rolling your own is a much larger task than you may realize. I suggest you peruse the [VT-220 reference manual](http://vt100.net/docs/vt220-rm/), VT-220 emulation being more or less the baseline for "console" functionality nowadays, and think hard about whether you really want to avoid the system libraries that deal with all of that for you.

Comment: @Zack I'm looking for a cross-platform solution, trying to abstract the gui as much as possible ( maybe using OpenGL for a basic GUI for example ) and make this really compatible with as many OSs as possible; I don't consider Windows as my main platform for this, if forced to decide I would like to keep Unix/linux Os like Android or Mac OS x or Ubuntu and discard Windows.

Comment: @Zack I have no idea how to do this, so I'm asking, if it's big or small, the only thing I know is that I really need a basic input/output solution ( without even OSs interfaces) .

Comment: You may want to consider cross platform libraries such as Qt?

Comment: @Acorbe Qt doesn't really "rocks" under Android or iOS for what I know, It's also a library that I don't really like, especially in the version number 5.x, the latest.

Comment: Have you even written a very basic console emulator? 
And no matter how you do this, you WILL have to use some system-specific functionality, as "the way a console works" is completely different in Linux/Unix/MacOS (using "pty", pseudo-terminals) and in Windows (not 100% sure how it actually works there, never really looked into it).

Comment: @MatsPetersson not even a clue, but I know that I need this like air to breathe. Imagine an Android application that is supposed to offer a Python interpreter inside the interface without a console emulator ...

Comment: Is that what you are actually trying to do? Run Python on Android?

Comment: @MatsPetersson it was an example, I need an **interface** where I can create a **terminal** and attach **console applications** to it

Comment: On Android specifically, or "on anything from MacOS, via Symbian to Windows"?

Comment: @MatsPetersson the more cross-plaform it is the better will be

Comment: bash gives you something

Comment: But also more difficult to achieve... Because for each (major) platform you wish to support, you will have to add a specific interface to support the GUI platform (although using OpenGL or OpenVG may help a little here - but most likely there will be some details like which graphics modes or features are supported that require tweaking, assuming there is support for it at all) and to support the "how to connect to another application from your code".

Comment: @MatsPetersson well, let's start with something, pick an OS that is simple for a newbie and let's see what is part of a generic console and what is platform specific.

Comment: I've just written a fairly generic answer. I'd suggest you start on one of the three parts that I describe there, and ask specific question on a specific OS to get further help. Like I say in the answer, it's quite a complex set of code, not something that is the "right size" as one single answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a WAY too large question for "one answer".

There are three components to the problem:

1. Running another application from your code.
2. Capturing the output of said application.
3. Displaying the output in a console type window.

I believe at least 1 & 2 are decidedly different for each major type of platform, at the very least it is different on Windows vs. Symbian vs. Linux/Unix type platforms. I believe, largely, an Android platform can achieve this by the same method as Linux.

The third part, aside from all the complexities of emulating a VT100 or ANSI terminal (which is non-trivial because there is a large number of different escape-codes to parse and interpret, but you can probably get away with just implementing half a dozen or so to begin with).

I'd expect, aside from "platform specific code", this is a project that requires a few thousand lines of code, and if you know where to start (that is, you are familiar with `fork(), execl()` etc in Linux or their equivalents in another OS, and familiar with redirection if `stdin`, `stderr` and `stdout` using `dup2()` and similar functions, again with reservation for OS specific names, you could have something that roughly works in a few weeks. If you have no idea about these things, you will have to learn how to use these features first.

Of course, doing terminal emulation, such as "draw a line of text here", "insert an empty line at line X", "clear screen from this position" or "clear remaining line", etc, etc will require a fair amount of work to cover ALL the different variants and options. Especially if you wish to do this on a variable size display, rather than a "fixed 80 columns and 25 rows" as the original VT100 terminals supported. And I'm assuming you have already written code to draw basic text in OpenGL or OpenVG (does OpenVG support text natively, or do you have to do that as "draw bitmap" - I can't remember exactly how it works - I wasn't one of the people working on text in Symbian Graphics, so I was never really concerned with how it worked).

Comment: I appreciate your answer but it's too vague, I need to see some C++ code and how to do this in practice at least on 1 platform so I know what the big picture is.

Comment: Which part? How to parse escape codes to clear the screen? Pick an OS!

Comment: one between a standard GNU/linux distribution and Android; I'm interested in the input ( passing user input to the app ) and output ( retrieving output from the app ) mechanism.

Comment: So, look at this to start with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476354/how-do-nix-pseudo-terminals-work-whats-the-master-slave-channel